# Standards mode in IE7 with HTML5?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, standards-compliance

Is there a way to trigger standards mode in IE7 when using the HTML5 doctype?

My document starts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Comment: If you've used the HTML5 doctype then IE7 should be in standards mode - how are you determining it's not?

Comment: The box model is broken. That's all I care about in this case.

Comment: Then maybe you should post the full code of (or a link to) where you're seeing the problem, rather than assuming your problem is the DOCTYPE?

Comment: i agree, we need to see more. can you put it in standards mode by changing the doctype?

Comment: To confirm the rendering mode, load the page and then type `javascript:alert(document.compatMode);` into the address bar - `CSS1Compat` means you're seeing standards mode

Comment: Are you actually testing in IE7 proper? Or using the emulation feature in IE8/9? They might not quite work in the same way...

Comment: Also, a bit of a long shot, but is there *any* chance something's putting a comment in before your DOCTYPE? That's about the only way to trigger quirks mode when using `<!DOCTYPE html>` as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

F12 opens Developer Tools in IE 9. Alt+7, Alt+8, & Alt 9 will allow you to toggle between browser versions. There are also menus that allow you to change both document and standards modes.

A couple things:

If you are trying to view the DOM tree using the developer tools and switching between different versions in compatibility mode, you should know that you need to refresh each time you switch modes. Otherwise you won't be able to see the tree.

Also, these emulations are not exactly like the original browsers. It really is impossible to see "the way another browser would render" a page unless you are on that other browser.

I recommend using [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org). It's free, and requires no download. If you want to get really sophisticated, there are other options. However I recommend browsershots. Just beware that it takes a few minutes to get a couple images back, and there is a maximum limit per day. You can raise that a bit by registering your account.

Answer (score -1):

Use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>` in the head section.